# Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant 1046

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I want to pulish SWF file from .fla file. I have some scripts there, but when I pulished them - they don't work. I get error from compiler:

```
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant

**Warning** The linkage identifier 'scrollableContent' was already assigned to the symbol 'pop_ups/__pop_up_other_elements/scrollableContent', and cannot be assigned to the symbol 'pop_ups/__pop_up_other_elements/scrollable_game_content', since linkage identifiers must be unique.
```

I google that error, but don't find any appropriate answer. 
I saw some information here, but it didn't help me. [http://curtismorley.com/20​07/06/20/flash-cs3-flex-2-​as3-error-1046/](http://curtismorley.com/20%E2%80%8B07/06/20/flash-cs3-flex-2-%E2%80%8Bas3-error-1046/)

Please, tell anybody what problem produce this error and how can I fix it? Thanx!

Comment: What *Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant*? Feels like you are missing an identifier. This does not sound like the entire error message.

Comment: Your mentioned page url seems wrong. the corrected one is http://curtismorley.com/2007/06/20/flash-cs3-flex-2-as3-error-1046/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official [compiler errors list](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/compilerErrors.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) on Adobe's site. In this case

**Error 1046**

> The class used as a type declaration is either unknown or is an
>   expression that could have different values at run time. Check that
>   you are importing the correct class and that its package location has
>   not changed. Also, check that the package that contains the code (not
>   the imported class) is defined correctly (for example, make sure to
>   use proper ActionScript 3.0 package syntax, and not ActionScript 2.0
>   syntax). The error can also occur if the class being referenced is not
>   defined in a namespace that is in use or is not defined as public:
>
> `public class Foo{}`

Check your .fla file to make sure you have all the links for assets properly. One simple case is that you have something on the stage with a name and one of your scripts has the same name. You cannot define it twice. Fix one of them.

Comment: Symbol 'dlg_startScreen' 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: game_con.

After delete “dlg_startScreen”
Symbol 'game_com' 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: scrollableContent.
Symbol 'game_com' 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: scroll.

Comment: I have such compile errors. Say, please, where I have to check for links to assets?

Answer (score 2):

So, I finded out reason, why that error was. Here is solution:

If, for example, you have 2 MovieClips:
movie1_mc, class linkage: "movie1"
movie2_mc, class linkage: "movie2"

And if movie1_mc is a child of movie2_mc, and also have its instance name same that its class linkage - error 1046 occurs.

So, the rule is:
If one file with class linkage is child of some other class, than its instance name must be different than its class linkage.